# Como Resolver esse desafio?

Tags: java, array

Desafio
O objetivo deste desafio é resolvê-lo utilizando o seu conhecimento sobre Arrays, uma estrutura de dados que armazena uma coleção de dados em um bloco de memória.

Você está desenvolvendo um sistema para um local de eventos, neste local, é necessário que a entrada seja permitida apenas para pessoas acima de 18 anos. Faça um programa para ler um número N, a idade de N pessoas. Depois disso, coloque a idade mínima permitida  para se entrar no local, conforme exemplo.
Retorne às idades de quem não puder entrar.

Entrada
A entrada será composta na primeira linha pelo tamanho da array e nas linhas subsequentes pelas idades que preenchem essa array

Saída
A saída deverá retornar as idades que não são permitidas a entrada, conforme exemplo abaixo.

Entrada
4
18
22
15
50

Saída
Nao poderao entrar as idades:
15

Entrada
3
50
10
65

Saída
Nao poderao entrar as idades:
10

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Locale;

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int N= scan.nextInt();
        String string = scan.nextLine();
    
        String[] s = string.split(" ");

        double[] idade = new double[N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            idade[i] =          ;
        }

        System.out.println("Nao poderao entrar as idades: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (           )
            {
                System.out.println(         );
            }

        }
               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi é pra adicionar os campos que estão vazios ?

Vamos lá, primeiro campo vazio que a gente percebeu foi o `idade[i] =          ;` ele antecede o laço de repetição `for` no campo vazio ele pede para a adicionar um valor que vai ser a  própria "idade".

Os próximos campos foram um "if" e um "sout", como é dito na questão apenas a saída deverá retornar as idades que não são permitidas a entrada que está rodando no laço anterior `(int i = 0; i < idades.length; i++) {`, logicamente o próximo seria para as entradas dos dados de +18 o que você preencheria `if (idades[i] < 18) {`, já no sout você poderia apenas puxar o `idade[i]`, pra ficar mais fácil pra você preenchi abaixo:

`public class ProibidoEntrada {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      
      //Quantidade de pessoas
      int quantidadePessoas = scan.nextInt();
      int[] idades = new int[quantidadePessoas];

    //Armazenando as idades em uma Array
    for (int i = 0; i < idades.length; i++) {

        int idade = scan.nextInt();
        idades[i] = idade;
        
    }

    System.out.println("Nao poderao entrar as idades: ");

    //testando maior de idade
    for (int i = 0; i < idades.length; i++) {
        if (idades[i] < 18) {

        }
        System.out.println(idades[i]);
    }

}
```

}`

Answer (score -1):

Fala pessoal, blz mesmo.
Esse codigo acima pra funcionar é preciso colocar o System.out.println(idades[i]) dentro do if, aí vai rodar filézinho.

Abraço a todos.